# Accessing First Member Coordinates of geoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I apologize if this is trivial or not possible, I am new to GIS. So I have a geoJSON file with thousands of members, each with a point coordinate. Is there a way for me to access the first coordinate (and the last, but I will deal with that later) of the geoJSON file?

Extraneous info: I am working on an html page using leaflet and have converted a CSV file into a geoJSON file, but I don't want the initial set view to be hard coded. I want it to be set, ideally to the center of the points, but being set to the first point will also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the [center point](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getcenter) of the [bounding box](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds) that surrounds the geoJSON layer:

```
var points = L.geoJson(json,{});
var center = points.getBounds().getCenter();
```

Once you have that, set the map view to be centered on that point:

```
// assumes you've already set up a map object with L.map({}); set zoom to some zoom level
map.setView(center,zoom);
```

as pointed out in the comment by @ghybs, you can also just fit the view to the bounds of the points, no need for a center point or zoom level:

```
map.fitBounds(points.getBounds());
```

Comment: And to view all of them: `map.fitBounds(points.getBounds())` With this you do not need to choose a zoom level.

Comment: good point - adding that to the answer

Comment: Where you have `var points = L.geoJson(json,{});` is json supposed to be my geoJSON file/data?

Comment: that is correct. If you add a more complete code sample to your question, I can try to be more specific your example